# How to access additional images (other than default_image) in Shoppe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently accessing the default_image in Shoppe using:

```
@product.default_image.path
```

but I can't seem to find the method to access additional images.

I'd like to write something like:

```
<% @product.image.each do |prodimg| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(prodimg.image.path, :width => '300px'), product_path(product.permalink) %>
<% end %>
```

I would appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There actually isn't "additional images" Shoppe uses a gem called "nifty-attachments" which allows you to link an image file directly to your database. In order to add more images you will need to add more "nifty-attachments" to your model.  See here: https://github.com/atech/nifty-attachments